# bootstrap dropdown for navbar not working (in angular)

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I have installed :`popper.js`, `bootstrap` and `jquery`.
My angular json file is:

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
           ],
"scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
           ]
```

In the `styles.css` file I import:
`@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`.

Even though I do these things my dropdown menu in the navbar is not working: my html code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I got the code from : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would advise you to seek alternatives to using jQuery in Angular. There are Angular-specific libraries that provide the javascript functionality of Bootstrap.

Comment: What error your are getting in terminal, console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are setting path to access you styles and scripts.

Node Modules is inside you main project folder; therefore skip one folder only, you are skipping/jumping two folder(../)

```
    "styles": [
       "src/styles.css",
       "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     ],
    "scripts": [
       "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
       "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
       "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
     ]
```

Comment: @sam can you give me correct answer( click on the up arrow in the left of answer)

Comment: the trinangle up and the check click to give me correct answer!

Comment: I did but my reputation is not high enough for it to be shown publicly

Comment: @sam it's impossibile! click on the triangle under the down arrow and it must wok